# Define/finding isosceles triangles from list

Tags: python-3.x, list, user-defined-functions, indices

I have a list of different triangles and I just want all the isosceles triangles.

```
valid = [[10, 105, 65], [13, 100, 67], [94, 77, 9], [35, 125, 20], [22, 4, 154], [60, 27, 93], [70, 40, 70], [37, 64, 79], [99, 14, 67], [128, 26, 26]]

def isosceles_1(valid):
    isosceles = []
    for value in valid:
        if i[0] ==i[1] or i[1]==i[2] or i[2]==i[0]:
            isosceles.append(i)
            return isosceles

isosceles_tri=[i for i in valid if isosceles_1(valid)]
print(len(isosceles_1(valid)))
```

I'm new to coding so please help

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: To find all the isosceles triangles in the list